# pki architecture with Spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, encryption, spring-security, cryptography, public-key-encryption

Hope you are doing well. My question is based on to secure REST API's.
We have to publish a rest API and we want only certain consumers to consume the API. I was thinking of one way is to use asymmetric encryption.
The steps I was about to follow:
(1) Generate a public/private key pair
(2) Export the public key in the form of X.509 certificate
(3) Share the public key with the client
(4) Client to use public key to encrypt data and make a POST Request on the API to send the encrypted data
(5) On the server, I'll decrypt the data using my private key and then store in the database

If an SSL certificate is already installed on the webserver and any API has to be called using https, is it not doing the same thing as per above?

That is where my confusion lies. Can someone help?

Thanks,
Ashley

Comment: The high-level goal is to authenticate the the API consumer to make sure she is allowed to access the API, and then perhaps to measure usage for billing purposes. It seems most everybody else uses an API key. Why do you think your scheme is better than using an API key?

Comment: As per some research made, I do not think API Key can be used for identifying users

Comment: I asked you why your scheme is *better* than an API key scheme. How can your scheme do any better at identifying users than an API key?

Comment: Oh ok. First it is not for billing purposes. Those consumers might share some confidential information. an API key can be easily stolen or shared.

Comment: A public key is just as easily stolen or shared.

Comment: It is too simplistic

Comment: If I decide to use client certificate as well, what is your opinion?